# Missing spell check in file extensions other than *.txt

Tags: release-loki, code

The Scratch spell check extension does not work with some file extensions such as *.tex or *.php in elementary OS Loki. Is there a workaround for this?

[image: File with *.txt extension]

[image: File with *.tex extension]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround. This is implemented in the [Spell plugin](https://github.com/elementary/scratch/blob/master/plugins/spell/spell.vala#L106) to deactivate Spell check in code files.

Comment: Any reason why?

Comment: I don‘t know why. In most languages code keywords are not part of the speller I suppose.